# List Comprehension for removing duplicates of characters in a string

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you remove duplicates from a list whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order)

So the idea is the program takes a string of characters and removes the same
             string with any duplicated character only appearing
             once -- removing any duplicated copy of a character.
So Iowa stays Iowa but the word eventually would become eventually

Answer (score 3):

Here is an inefficient method:

```
x = 'eventually'
newx = ''.join([c for i,c in enumerate(x) if c not in x[:i]])
```

I don't think that there is an efficient way to do it in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

Here it is as an **O(n)** (average case) generator expression. The others are all roughly O(n<sup>2</sup>).

```
chars = set()
string = "aaaaa"
newstring = ''.join(chars.add(char) or char for char in string if char not in chars)
```

It works because [`set.add`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.add) returns `None`, so the `or` will always cause the character to be yielded from the generator expression when the character isn't already in the `set`.

**Edit:** Also see refaim's solutions. My solution is like his second one, but it uses the `set` in the opposite way.

My take on his `OrderedDict` solution:

```
''.join(OrderedDict((char, None) for char in word))
```

Comment: To be frank, these aren't pure list comprehension solutions (and neither are refaim's) and I'm not saying that because of generator expressions. I'm saying it because they require another line like defining a set or importing OrderedDict. It's not a big deal because this is kind of a stupid question anyway, but I thought that I would point it out.

Comment: @JustinPeel See Matt's golfed version of my answer. I could do the same for `OrderedDict` with `__import__`. They're just _more Pythonic_ with another line, they don't _require_ another line. Remember, questions and answers are for all the people who Google this in the future, not just the person asking. That's what makes bad questions like this worth answering to me -- giving an answer better than the naive one that might be useful or interesting to someone in the future. Not following arbitrary restrictions. It's not code golf. "Elegant" has value. One-line for one-line's sake doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Without list comprehensions:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

word = 'eventually'
print ''.join(OrderedDict(zip(word, range(len(word)))).keys())
```

With list comprehensions (quick and dirty solution):

```
word = 'eventually'
uniq = set(word)
print ''.join(c for c in word if c in uniq and not uniq.discard(c))
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't see yours before I posted mine, they're similar. I also added a modified version of your `OrderedDict` method to my answer. Also, it's a generator expression not a list comprehension :)

Comment: Yeah, yours `OrderedDict` method is more fast and accurate than mine.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s='eventually'
>>> "".join([c for i,c in enumerate(s) if i==s.find(c)])
'evntualy'
```

note that using a list comprehension with `join()` is silly when you can just use a generator expression. You should tell your teacher to update their question

Answer (score 0):

You could make a `set` from the string, then join it together again.  This works since sets can only contain unique values.  **The order wont be the same though**:

```
In [1]: myString = "mississippi"

In [2]: set(myString))
Out[2]: set(['i', 'm', 'p', 's'])

In [3]: print "".join(set(myString))
Out[3]: ipsm

In [4]: set("iowa")
Out[4]: set(['a', 'i', 'o', 'w'])

In [5]: set("eventually")
Out[5]: set(['a', 'e', 'l', 'n', 't', 'u', 'v', 'y'])
```

Edit: Just saw the "List Comprehension" in the title so this probably isnt what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Create a set from the original string, and then sort by position of character in original string:

```
>>> s='eventually'
>>> ''.join(sorted(set(s), key=s.index))
'evntualy'
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order), I think this is the fastest way:

```
>>> def remove_dupes(str):
...    chars = set()
...    chars_add = chars.add
...    return ''.join(c for c in str if c not in chars and not chars_add(c))
... 
>>> remove_dupes('hello')
'helo'
>>> remove_dupes('testing')
'tesing'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word = "eventually"
evntualy = ''.join(
     c 
     for d in [dict(zip(word, word))] 
         for c in word 
     if d.pop(c, None) is not None)
```

Riffing off of agf's (clever) solution but without making a set outside of the generator expression:

```
evntualy = ''.join(s.add(c) or c for s in [set()] for c in word if c not in s)
```